# Set of elements yielding Reals when squared

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

Set $S$ is the set of all complex numbers that can be squared to yield a real number. I solved by considering a complex number $z$ and setting the imaginary portion of its square equal to $0$.

$$\begin{align}
& \Im\left(z^2\right)=0 \\
& \Im\left((a+bi)^2\right)=0,\,a,b\in\mathbb{R} \\
& 2ab=0 \\
& ab=0 \\
\end{align}$$

This means that $a=0$ **or** $b=0$:

$$\begin{align}
& a+bi\to 0+bi=bi \\
& a+bi\to a+0i=a \\
\end{align}$$

This means that $S$ is a union of the set of real numbers and the set of pure imaginary numbers. Are there any alternative ways to go about proving this?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to convert the complex number to its polar form.

Consider a complex number $z$:

$$\begin{align}
& \Im\left(z^2\right)=0 \\
& \Im\left(m\cdot e^{2\theta i}\right)=0 \\
& 2m\cdot\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=0 \\
& \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=0 \\
\end{align}$$

This means that $(\cos(\theta)=0)$ + $(\sin(\theta)=0)$

$$\begin{align}
& \cos(\theta)=0 \\
\implies& \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n,\,n\in\mathbb{Z} \\
& \sin(\theta)=0 \\
\implies& \theta=\pi n,\,n\in\mathbb{Z} \\
\end{align}$$

This means that:

$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}n,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Therefore, $S$ is comprised only of numbers that form an angle measuring a multiple of $90^{\circ}$ on the complex plane. In other words, numbers on the real and imaginary axes of the complex plane.